# How to check only the enabled checkboxes in a datagrid using checkboxheader in c#?

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have a Datagrid, named ShowGrid. The first column of the Datagrid is a Checkbox column and I have a CheckboxHeader for Checking/Unchecking all the rows in the Datagrid.

I can also select particular row checkbox for a Buttonclick.After the Buttonclick, I disable the particular rows's Checkbox.

After this, if I check the checkboxHeader, the disabled checkbox is also getting checked. So how can I select only the enabled checkboxes on checking on CheckboxHeader. I have used the following code, But I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception.

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ShowGrid.Rows)
            {
                if ((bool)row.Cells[0].Value == true && (bool)row.Cells[0].ReadOnly == false)
                {
                    ShowGrid[0, row.Index].Value = ((CheckBox)ShowGrid.Controls.Find("checkboxHeader", true)[0]).Checked;
                }
            }          
        ShowGrid.EndEdit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your if statement code as following

```
if (row.Cells != null &&(bool)row.Cells[0].Value == true && (bool)row.Cells[0].ReadOnly == false)
            {
                ShowGrid[0, row.Index].Value = ((CheckBox)ShowGrid.Controls.Find("checkboxHeader", true)[0]).Checked;
            }
```